# How to extract date from a DateNow() in YYYYMMDD format in SQL Server

Tags: date, sql-server-2005, getdate

Got a specific requirement that we should extract only date and in YYYYMMDD format from GETDATE() in Sql-Server 2005.

How can I accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use formatting in your sql query:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Your query should be

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]
```